# How to sum on a groupBy with an iterator?

Tags: scala

given `Iterator[(String, Int)]`

I would like to group by the `String` and sum the `Int` and return the results as a `Map[String, Int]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to a list or other strict structure:

```
iter.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

If you don't want to convert to a strict structure (which forces all of the entries into memory), you can `foldLeft` and build the map as you go:

```
(Map.empty[String,Int] /: iter) {case (acc, (k,v)) => 
  acc + (k -> acc.get(k).map(_ + v).getOrElse(v))
}
```

Comment: In which sense is the second version lazy? Isn't the fold evaluated at once?

Comment: @lex82 I suppose lazy is the wrong word. Yes, it is evaluated at once. It just doesn't hold all of the individual entries in memory as converting it to list would. It only holds the totals and a single entry at a time.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think `toTraversable` instead of `toList` would solve this problem in many cases, too, without having to implement the `groupBy` logic again. Not sure whether it would yield a Stream rather then materializing the iterator in all cases.